# Android database connection how to connect with serverdb?

Tags: android, database, live

How to connect the live database in android? if anyone know pls tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You should either use web services or implement an HTTP handler and transfer in a RESTful manner

Answer (score 0):

you use the webservice (url) like php,.net,python.then data stored in the database using the webservice.and response from the server like xml and json.you make the connection to the sever through the get and post request from the server.